# How to add .well-known/change-password in Magento?

Tags: magento2, browser

I would like to add the lasted best practices to my Magento 2.4 and help users change passwords easily by adding a well-known URL for changing passwords.

Technology Reference: https://web.dev/change-password-url/

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 easy and 1 difficult way.

### 1º Redirect

Add a redirect direct from your host panel, from https://example.com/.well-known/change-password to https://example.com/customer/account/forgotpassword

##### Varnish

Or create a VCL redirect like this below, where you create your new folder and file inside the media folder and redirect the access to it.

```
if ( req.url.path == "/.well-known/change-password" ) { set req.url = "/media/.well-known/change-password"; }
```

### 2º File

Alternatively you can serve HTML at your **.well-known/change-password** URL with a `<meta>` tag using an `http-equiv="refresh"`.

**File**

```
pub/.well-known/change-password
```

**Content**

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://example.com/customer/account/forgotpassword">
```

### 3º Module

The hardest way would be creating a module to redirect `.well-known/change-password` to your **forgot password** page.